# Saving Files on Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, file, tapi

I am developing a Call Center application for landline phone in C#.

5 Clients are connected to Server using LAN.

I am using voice modem on Clients to attach landline phones

This app saves/retrieves history of caller from Server using MS SQL Server(installed on Server), 
but saves recording on Client because it records the call using voice modem and saves it directly on the Client.

**Now I want to transfer these audio recorded files on Server whenever Client finished the recording, But I don't need to do efficient searching of Audio Files on the Server**

I Considered the following scenarios

**1)** Transfer files using TCP/IP, Make routine for Server that receives files, and make a routine for client to send files. 
It will flop when the routine on  Server is not running.

**2)** Save the files directly on MS SQL Server 
but It will create unwanted burden on MS SQL Server

I Need help to solve this problem efficiently

Comment: You can perhaps using message queuing mechanism whereby when you want to transfer files, place it on the queue then have an asynchronous calls to move the files. MSMQ is an example and I believe will handle all the error handling for you too so will perform retries etc.

Comment: Still I don't have any idea about MSMQ, but it seems to be a good idea

Comment: What you don't want to be doing is handling issues such as a file server being down etc, that is something you can delegate to another tool to do. Ideally you want to be focusing on the business logic, i.e. recording the content and ensuring its saved. This way you can ignore SQL Server potentially as you can store the files on the client machine and have them uploaded to a server.